# Google Maps marker only disappears after zooming on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I'm having some strange behaviour on my HTC one when it comes to a google maps app built with phonegap:

There is always one active marker on the map. If a new one is set, the old is removed with `marker.setMap(null)`, which works perfectly fine in all desktop browser and also on the iPhone. But, on the Android phone, the marker sometimes doesn't disappear, even though the function is called. If this happens, you can make it disappear with zooming in and out a few times, and then it's gone.

I guess the problem is that the map is only rendered newly after the zooming. I tried to simulate that with the following code:

```
marker.setMapp(null);
google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
```

I also tried to set the markers visibility and the position, but neither of it would work. Has anyone ever seen that behaviour before?

**Edit**: The problem only appears on the Android default browser. If I open the webversion of the app via Chrome, it all works fine. But if I open the exact same version in the default Browser, the marker problem appears again.

**Edit 2**: I finally solved the problem using following code after the marker.setMap(null) is called:

```
var zoom = map.getZoom();
map.setZoom(1);
map.setZoom(zoom);
```

But it's a very ugly, so I'm still searching for a "real" and clean solution.

Comment: What if you do `marker.setVisible(false)` before `setMap(null)`?

Comment: tried that already. I'm almost 100% sure that the problem has something to do with the map not rendering again.

Comment: What about if you force rendering? I am not sure if you can use [hint from this article](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-force-browser-render-on-elements.html)

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but unfortunately without success..